# How to get the images and data stored in the database?

Tags: php

I have created a database namely newwork and table name property. In this database I have stored user details and one image. Now I want to display all the data from one field and stored image from the same field in a new page. Please help me for this program. The fields are property_id, property, location, image.

Answer (score 1):

You really need two parts here (one to build the HTML and another to fetch/display the image):

Part 1:  HTML builder

```
<?php 
  $res = mysqli_query($cnx, 'SELECT property_id, property, location from newwork';
  if (res)
  {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
    { 
        echo '<span class="property">'.$row['property'].'</span>';
        echo '<span class="location">'.$row['location'].'</span>';
        echo '<span class="photo"><img src="image.php?id='.$row['property_id'].'" /></span>
    }
  }
```

Part 2:  Image builder

```
<?php
  $res = mysqli_query($cnx, 'SELECT image 
                             FROM newwork 
                             WHERE property_id='.intval($_REQUEST['id']));
  if ($res) 
  {
     $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
     if (!empty($row))
     {
       header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
       echo $row['image'];
       exit;
     }
  }
  header('Location: error_image.jpg',TRUE,302);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest going though this step by step tutorial

http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/index.php